# How to check memory leak of java application in a core dump file?

Tags: java, linux, memory-leaks, pid, coredump

On of my jboss application suddenly stoped and core dump file got generated in /var/crash/ path with process id. There is no log generated in same location. Java version is java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.45.x86_64. I want to know why my application got killed and this file got generated. Am suspecting some memory leak happened which cause this failure. But there is no trace in application log. How to debug this code dump file (its about 6 GB )

Comment: If this has never happened before the first thing need to do is trying to reproduce it. In the event that you find something if you can'r reproduce it how do you plan to fix it?

Comment: This issue happend in my production system where i cannot do any testing. Unfortunately am not able to reproduce it in my test environment. From production i got core dump file only, no trace from application log

Comment: It still requires reading the core dump. Can you post it? I am afraid that you will have to wait until it happens again to really start fixing it

Comment: Your core-dump could have many reasons, not only memory-leaks. Don't draw premature conclusions before you analysed the java core-dump and the `hs_err_pid*.log` file. See also [Analysing a Java Core Dump](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/analysing-a-java-core-dump.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since i can't see our dump file, so i can't say exactly its memory leak.
For memory leak checking many tools are there in running applications. 
Inside JDK also VisualVM tool is there in "JDK/bin" folder.
You can point it to your production server.

Other multiple solutions are provided @ https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/08/14/find-fix-memory-leaks-java-application/